# Updating the dependencies from composer issues mcrypt error in PHP

Tags: php, git, mcrypt, orocrm

After cloning from Git I tried to update the dependencies from composer.
Even though php7.1 mcrypt is installed

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt php7.1-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mcrypt is already the newest version (2.6.8-1.3ubuntu1).
php7.1-mcrypt is already the newest version (7.1.13-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm4.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

---

**The following errors occurs**

```
 YYY@YYY:/var/www/html/orocrm$ sudo composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev
```

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - oro/platform 2.x-dev requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - oro/platform 2.x-dev requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle 2.x-dev requires oro/platform 2.x-dev -> satisfiable by oro/platform[2.x-dev].
    - Installation request for oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle 2.x-dev -> satisfiable by oro/crm-hangouts-call-bundle[2.x-dev].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How am I suppose to resolve the mcrypt error? Since Mcrypt is deprecated in PHP 7.x documentation.

---

According to Magnus Eriksson

I tried to use PECL library to install
I have followed this link:
[Installing mcrypt on PHP 7.2](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-mcrypt-extension.html) to install!

```
root@YYY:/var/www/html/orocrm# apt install php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm4.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-pear
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 285 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,107 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 php-pear all 1:1.10.5+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [285 kB]
Fetched 285 kB in 1s (230 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package php-pear.
(Reading database ... 215503 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php-pear_1%3a1.10.5+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-pear (1:1.10.5+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up php-pear (1:1.10.5+submodules+notgz-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

YYY@YYY:/var/www/html/orocrm$ sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
[sudo] password for YYY: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libc6-dev' instead of 'libc-dev'
gcc is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
make is already the newest version (4.1-6).
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu1).
libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.23-0ubuntu9).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm4.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
Suggested packages:
  autoconf-archive gnu-standards autoconf-doc libtool
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autoconf automake autotools-dev libsigsegv2 m4
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,079 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,998 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libsigsegv2 amd64 2.10-4 [14.1 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 m4 amd64 1.4.17-5 [195 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 autoconf all 2.69-9 [321 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 autotools-dev all 20150820.1 [39.8 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 automake all 1:1.15-4ubuntu1 [510 kB]
Fetched 1,079 kB in 2s (447 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package libsigsegv2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 215198 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsigsegv2_2.10-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.10-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package m4.
Preparing to unpack .../archives/m4_1.4.17-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking m4 (1.4.17-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package autoconf.
Preparing to unpack .../autoconf_2.69-9_all.deb ...
Unpacking autoconf (2.69-9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package autotools-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../autotools-dev_20150820.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking autotools-dev (20150820.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package automake.
Preparing to unpack .../automake_1%3a1.15-4ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking automake (1:1.15-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Setting up libsigsegv2:amd64 (2.10-4) ...
Setting up m4 (1.4.17-5) ...
Setting up autoconf (2.69-9) ...
Setting up autotools-dev (20150820.1) ...
Setting up automake (1:1.15-4ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/automake-1.15 to provide /usr/bin/automake (automake) in auto mode
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
YYY@YYY:/var/www/html/orocrm$ sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm4.0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmcrypt-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 83.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 438 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libmcrypt-dev amd64 2.5.8-3.3 [83.7 kB]
Fetched 83.7 kB in 0s (105 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package libmcrypt-dev.
(Reading database ... 215484 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmcrypt-dev_2.5.8-3.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmcrypt-dev (2.5.8-3.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libmcrypt-dev (2.5.8-3.3) ...

YYY@YYY:/var/www/html/orocrm$ sudo pecl7.2-sp install --nodeps mcrypt-snapshot
sudo: pecl7.2-sp: command not found
```

As I'm getting this type of Error as ***pecl7.2-sp: command not found***

How do I have to solve the above issue?

Comment: You're installing mcrypt for PHP 7.1 while you seem to be using PHP 7.2. Please check your PHP version using: `php -v`. **Note:** mcrypt got deprectaded in PHP 7.1 and was dropped from the core in PHP 7.2. If you _really_ need it (which you shouldn't since it is a dead library since many years back), you need to install it through PECL.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Will you check the updated/edited post... I'm getting as pecl7.2-sp: command not found

Comment: They are working on removing that dependency. It appears that they aren't even using it. https://github.com/oroinc/platform/issues/782. Instead of jumping through hoops trying to install a deprecated and unused library, just go with PHP 7.0 or PHP 7.1 until they have removed it from their composer file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Magnus Eriksson and would suggest to you to switch to php7.1, cause ORO Platform has a dependency on the ext-mcrypt. The same issue has already been discussed on the [GitHub](https://github.com/oroinc/platform/issues/782).